# Add global variables with node commands inside

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to add one global variable to be accessible by all jobs inside my gitlab.yml file:

```
variables:
  VERSION: $(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
```

Which is meant to fetch the node version of the package.json file but the issue here is that when I try to access the variable $VERSION, it does nothing but print the value as a string and not implement it in the release job below:

```
release-job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH 
  script:
    - echo "running release-job for $TAG"
  release: 
  tag_name: 'v0.$CI_PIPELINE_IID'
  description: 'This is the new version: v0.$CI_PIPELINE_IID and 
  package.json = $VERSION'
  ref: '$CI_COMMIT_SHA' # The tag is created from the pipeline SHA.
  tags:
  - SharedRunner
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "when I try to access the variable $VERSION" — How do you try to do that?

Comment: "print the value as a string" — print where?

Comment: "and not implement it" — What, specifically, does "implement" mean in this context?